# How to add Repository maven in new Android Studio Project setup(2022)?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, maven

I want to use the [maven library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) in the android studio project. in the library documentation, they mention adding like this,

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
}
```

But in the new android studio `build.gradle` file looks like this

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

So, how do I want to add this library repository, Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the latest Android Studio Bumblebee(2021.1.1) version, if you see it in `build.gradle(Project)` the **new structure** looks like this

> `build.gradle(Project)`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

In order to use the other libraries like `maven`, you have to go to the `settings.gradle` and you have to the maven link like below

> `settings.gradle`

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } // add like this
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } // add like this
    }
}
rootProject.name = "your project name here"
include ':app'
```

[image: setting.gradle]

> finally add the library in to your `Build.gradle(module)`

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to add the maven url to settings.gradle.kt file
Add like this:

**maven {url = uri("https://www.jitpack.io" ) }**

This line worked for me on 3. October. 2023

Comment: Thank you so much. While using `Android Studio Hedgehog` then we must use like this to specify `maven url`

Answer (score 6):

Referring to [answer from Prasath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72224561/13755907), I would simplify the answer.
In old gradle structure you have a line in Project build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } // this is your line
}
```

In new gradle structure you have to add a line in setting.gradle like this:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } //  // this is your line
    }
}
```

You do not have to add the line in pluginManagement{} section in settings.gradle.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had a lot of confusion with this, but I was able to solve it this way, I just added Maven in Settings.gradle, when I added twice this caused me conflicts, but when I tried just adding once then it worked correctly.

I am using Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1.

[image: how to add Maven Jitpack.io on Android 2022]